# Curl from App Container failing with Istio

Tags: networking, azure-aks, istio, envoyproxy, kubernetes-networking

Have istio integrated to the k8s cluster. I am trying to curl to a etcd pod behind headless service (one of three pods) from the ubuntu pod (this pod also has envoy) in the same namespace.

I am seeing 404 page not found when I curl to the headless service etcd pods.

I tried creating a virtual service and destination rule

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: etcd-route-rule
  namespace: aks-istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  http:
   - route:
      - destination:
          host: <etcd-pod>.<headless-svc-name>.ns.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 2380
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: etcd-mtls-dstrule
  namespace: aks-istio-system
spec:
  host: <etcd-pod>.<headless-svc-name>.ns.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
     mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

I started getting 503 error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Arko Updated with just service, I am getting 404 page not found.

Answer (score 0):

To set up your environment correctly and avoid the errors you're encountering with Istio and your etcd service, follow these steps:

Deploy Your etcd Cluster with a Headless Service

1. Deploy etcd Pods: Ensure your etcd pods are deployed in Kubernetes. You might be using a StatefulSet for this, which is typical for etcd clusters.
2. Create a Headless Service: Define a headless service in Kubernetes for your etcd cluster. Here's an example service definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: etcd-headless
  namespace: aks-istio-system
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2380
    name: peer
  - port: 2379
    name: client
  clusterIP: None  # This makes the service headless
  selector:
    app: etcd  # Adjust this selector to match your etcd pods
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Install and Configure Istio to enable automatic sidecar injection
[image]

```
kubectl label namespace aks-istio-system istio-injection=enabled
```

[image]

Ensure that your etcd pods have the Istio sidecar injected. If they were running before Istio was enabled, you might need to recreate the pods.
[image]

next configure Istio Networking by creating a VirtualService to manage the traffic to your etcd headless service and a DestinationRule to specify traffic policies, such as TLS settings.

*virtualService.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: etcd-route-rule
  namespace: aks-istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "etcd-headless.aks-istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: "etcd-headless.aks-istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
        port:
          number: 2379  # or 2380 depending on the port you want to access
```

*DestinationRule.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: etcd-destination-rule
  namespace: aks-istio-system
spec:
  host: "etcd-headless.aks-istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE  # Use ISTIO_MUTUAL if you want mTLS
```

[image]

Now that the Istio networking objects are in place, you can test the connectivity. Since the `etcd` pods are likely to be part of the etcd cluster itself and might not have `curl` installed, you'll need a separate pod within the `aks-istio-system` namespace that has `curl` available. If you don't have a suitable pod already, you can create a temporary one for testing purposes. Here's how you can deploy a simple Ubuntu pod and then use it to test the connectivity. Create a file named `ubuntu-pod.yaml` with the following content:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-test
  namespace: aks-istio-system
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu
    command: ["/bin/sleep", "infinity"]
```

Deploy the pod

```
kubectl apply -f ubuntu-pod.yaml
```

Once pod is up, exec into it.

```
kubectl exec -it ubuntu-test -n aks-istio-system -- bash
```

[image]
and install curl

```
apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y
```

and finally `curl http://etcd-headless.aks-istio-system.svc.cluster.local:2379/health`

[image]